# How to stop build trigger if commit is made to the Jenkins pipeline as a code (Pipeline script for SCM setup)

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, git-checkout, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using Jenkins declarative pipeline as a code (Pipeline script for SCM setup) for running CI/CD pipeline. In my pipeline code I have a Git Checkout configuration for my project to be build and deploy.

[image]

```
stage ('GIT CHECKOUT')
    {
        steps
        {
            script 
            { 
              gitCheckout
            }
        }    
    }
```

My pipeline is configured with pollSCM property, pipeline polls my project's git repository every 1 minute, if any, change is found in the project CI/CD pipeline is triggered.

```
triggers 
{ 
    pollSCM('* * * * *') 
}
```

The issue I am facing currently is pollSCM is working fine, but If I make any change in my pipeline CI/CD gets triggered for the project.

I am using Jenkins shared libs design for building my project, let's say my pipeline name is SpringBootV2Jenkins.txt.
The issue I am facing is

- Any commit in SpringBootV2Jenkins.txt is triggering the CI/CD pipeline.
- Any commit in shared libs groovy files is triggering the CI/CD pipeline.

My requirement is CI/CD pipeline should trigger only when there is a change in the project git repository, not in the CI/CD pipeline as code repository

Comment: you meant, you changed in Jenkinsfile, the trigger is started, right?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes ur correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude jenkins files from scm polling on a jenkins job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650259/how-to-exclude-jenkins-files-from-scm-polling-on-a-jenkins-job)

Comment: @theonlyrao no I tried this option it is not working